# Как вычислить возраст в С#?

Tags: c#

почему при вычитании двух дат типа `DateTime` получается значение типа TimeSpan, и как мне получить отсюда результат типа `DateTime`?

```
public int Age()
{
    return (DateTime.Now - BirthDate)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Разницу между датами нельзя перевести в года, т.к. в каждом календарном году свое количество дней. Т.е. разница в 365 дней может быть как полным годом, так и неполным, в зависимости от даты отсчета.

Так что придется сравнивать года и даты вручную:

```
public static int GetAge(DateTime birthDate)
{
    var now = DateTime.Today;
    return now.Year - birthDate.Year - 1 + 
        ((now.Month > birthDate.Month || now.Month == birthDate.Month && now.Day >= birthDate.Day) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

[Более красивое решение от Mike Polen:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404/1988244)

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
int age = now.Year - bday.Year;
if (bday > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
```

---

По той же причине - разной продолжительности года - нельзя просто взять и прибавить количество дней / тиков / к какой-то базовой дате (например, к 01.01.0001) и использовать полученное значение в качестве возраста.

Такое решение может показаться удобным и простым, но, к сожалению, оно будет давать неверные результаты в достаточно тривиальных случаях.

Comment: А годы почему добавлять можно? А если к 29 февраля добавить?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно добавлять что угодно, но нельзя добавлять фиксированный интервал какой-то базовой дате. Год - не фиксированный интервал, реальная добавленная разница при вызове AddYear зависит от первоначальной даты. на 29-м февраля - взрывается.

Comment: Да, видимо, работает: https://ideone.com/Qa1aUJ. И при `>=` тоже: https://ideone.com/zyNpCR. Я почему-то был уверен, что что-то из этого можно сломать.