# Расчет времени от даты рождения до текущей даты

Tags: c#, datetime

**Условие:**

Есть текущая дата - `DateTime current = DateTime.Now;`

Есть дата рождения - `DateTime BirthDate = new DateTime(1970, 04, 06);`

**Задача:** Вывести переменную для расчета времени прошедшего от **BirthDate** до **current**

Comment: (BirthDate - current).TotalDays

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD другим очки даю заработать. А если честно, то я очень ленивый человек =(

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, я тоже ленивый, но когда постят плохие ответы, я не могу молчать :)

Comment: На случай, если вы пытаетесь вычислить возраст в годах - [Как вычислить возраст в С#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669903/177221). Только обратите внимание - вычислить возраст в формате yy, mm, dd нельзя - т.к. месяц - не постоянная величина.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто отнимите от текущей даты дату рождения и получите результат в [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var t = BirthDate - current;
```

У структуры `DateTime` для этого специально перегружен оператор: [public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1905yhe2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, подходит. Осталось допишу метод на вывод даты в формате (yy, mm, dd).

Comment: @Rifter: Этот метод уже существует и называется `ToString`. Только подберите подходящую форматную строку.

Comment: @VladD точно, спасибо

Comment: @VladD для TimeSpan нет форматирования в годы / месяцы :)

Comment: @PashaPash, кстати да - придется собирать вручную: [Строки стандартного формата TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx) и [Строки пользовательского формата TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Андрей и руками тоже не получится. TimeSpan - это длительность. А год / месяц - отрезок переменной длительности. один январь != один февраль в TimeSpan.

Comment: Можно придумать какой-нибудь хак типа: `new DateTime() + t`, хотя, тут, конечно, есть нюанс с високосными годами

Comment: @Андрей ...и результат будет зависеть от текущей даты. и от високосности текущего года (даже если вычисление проводится в январе). Можно написать код вида https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669903/177221 - для вывода полных лет (и, по аналогии, полных месяцев и полных дней) - но тогда вопрос - дубликат :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Кстати, да. А правда, день рождения 29 февраля високосного года, сегодня 28 февраля или первое марта следующего года — что выводить?